# How to decide session time out ms in Kafka low level processor API

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

So suppose punctuate time is X min/sec

```
{
props.put("group.max.session.timeout.ms", X*2);
props.put("session.timeout.ms", x);
props.put("request.timeout.ms", X*2);
}
```

Is above is correct way to set session time out for Kafka streams low level processor API ?

Comment: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured session.timeout.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

Comment: which version of kafka are you using, they split the poll and processing into separate threads in 0.10.2.0

Comment: @katsharp that independent -- there is still `max.poll.interval.ms`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `group.max.session.timeout.ms` is a broker setting (cf. http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs
- for consumer setting within Streams, it's recommended to use prefix `consumer.`: `props.put("consumer.session.timeout.ms", X)`
- you should set `max.poll.interval.ms` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (Streams will change the default value for this to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, too)